# PL/SQL procedure definitions in DB2 as USER_ARGUMENTS in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, db2

In **Oracle** DB, we can get the definition of PLSQL procedures and function (Like argument, its order and datatypes) from the table **USER_ARGUMENTS**.
I am looking for a similar source of data in case of **DB2**.

Comment: Which platform are you running DB2 on?

Comment: It is running on Linux Machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows here.

Try looking at the [`SYSCAT.ROUTINEPARMS`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001044.html) catalog view.  Probably something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINEPARMS
WHERE ROUTINESCHEMA = @schema
  AND ROUTINENAME   = @name
ORDER BY ORDINAL
```